# How do I force HBase to run on HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I was using HBase on the native file system and created a few tables. Now I configured HDFS and want HBase to use that instead. I started Namenode and Datanode, but am not able to find a setting where I can tell HBase to use HDFS.

I thought it might pick up HDFS upon a restart, so I did that (stop-hbase + start-hbase), but I am still able to see the table I created earlier on the native file system.

**How can I tell HBase to use HDFS?**

Answer (score 4):

In $HBASE_HOME/conf/hbase-site.xml `hbase.rootdir` defines the filesystem/directory where HBase persists. See:
http://hbase.apache.org/book/config.files.html#hbase_default_configurations

I assume you want to configure HBase in *pseudo-distributed* mode. If so set the followings in `hbase-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  ...
</configuration>
```

In this case HBase will use the **/hbase** directory in your HDFS.

Comment: If I am using the stand alone mode of hbase and hadoop then hbase.rootdir will have the same value or else?